# Возможно ли программно загрузить внешнюю обработку в 1С?

Tags: 1с

Есть файл с внешней обработкой, который нужно подключить к 1С автоматически. То есть способ "зайти в режиме конфигуратора или в 1С:Предприятие, выбрать файл обработки..." не подходит. Запустить просто с ярлыка на запуск тоже нельзя - на это нет прав.

Удалось нагуглить справочник "ДополнительныеОтчетыИОбработки". Но такое ощущение, что в него все равно предварительно нужно вручную загружать обработку. А нужно, грубо говоря, что-то вроде:

```
ВолшебныйОбъект.ЗагрузитьОбработкуИзФайлаВКонфигурацию("C:\tmp\МояОбработка.epf");
обработка = Конфигурация.ПолучитьОбработкуПоИмени("МояОбработка");
обработка.ВсеПолучилосьВсеСчастливы();
```

То есть полностью программная загрузка, которую можно было бы вызвать допустим по Http и пользователю ничего бы не надо было делать, максимум - положить обработку в нужную папку.

Возможно ли такое сделать в принципе? И если да, то подскажите объекты, которые в этой задаче будут полезны.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял - ты хочешь программно добавить обработку в Справочник.ДополнительныеОтчетыИОбработки; Так для этого открой конфигуратор, перейди к `ФормаЭлемента` `Справочник.ДополнительныеОтчетыИОбработки`, и посмотри код кнопки добавления !

Answer (score 0):

Внешнюю обработку можно загрузить, как двоичные данные. Т.е. создать объект «ДвоичныеДанные» с путем к внешней обработке. После этого можешь делать с двоичными данными что захочешь: сохрани в другой папке, сохрани в справочнике (аля «ДополнительныеОтчетыИОбработки»), сохрани в своём справочнике (положить ДД в реквизит типа «ХранилищеЗначения») или сразу передавай по HTTP.

Т.к. тебе нужно передавать её по HTTP, то это однозначно должен быть справочник обработок, хотя бы простейший, который будет хранить двоичные данные внешней обработки. А по HTTP просто обращаешься к этому справочнику и в ответ отправляешь двоичные данные из реквизита типа «ХранилищеЗначения» нужного элемента справочника